# Source code embedded in list

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to include source code snippets as part of list items, like so

```
1. I tried this as root
   #+begin_src shell
   rm -rf /
   #+end_src
2. Now the computer won't boot.
```

but `org-meta-return` after the source doesn't give the next number, it starts a new headline.  How can I include code as part of the list and not have it terminate the list?  (The same question applies to `#+begin_quote`/`#+end_quote`.)

Comment: I cant reproduce this. I see numberings in my orgmode. which version of org-mode you are using.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either.  `Org Version 7.7` (and 7.8.03) on `Emacs 24.0.92.1`.

Comment: Am I too out of date? `GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.4) of 2011-04-04 on crested, modified by Debian` and
`release_7.4-545-g56399
Org-mode version 7.4 (release_7.4.545.g56399)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your version of Org-Mode I would recommend updating to a newer version, `7.4` was released 13 months ago.

If I'm reading your release string properly you are currently using commit `56399` that was submitted on `[2011-02-27 Sun 11:01]`.  Since then there have been 1983 commits and the version number has been pushed up to `7.8.03` (currently shipping with `7.7` I believe).

For information on how to update to the newest version please see:
[Download and install Org-Mode](http://orgmode.org/org-mode-download.html)
[How to keep up to date](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#keeping-current-with-Org-mode-development)

You should also be able to update by using `apt-get install org-mode` in Debian and Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 11.10 has `7.6` (which may or may not have the desired change, you'd have to see) in it's repository and 12.04 has `7.8.02`.  If you're running Debian it looks like Sid has 7.8.02 in it as well.

Comment: I am running Debian squeeze (stable).  However, I have a separate clone of the org-mode git repo.  I did a fresh pull and now it works.